# Memcached + Redis for news feed

Tags: database, redis, memcached, stackexchange.redis

I'm planning to build caches on top of my MYSQL database for a news feed activities.

I just read that Memcached handles  metadata more efficiently than does Redis. So I'm wondering if it would make sense for me to store "normalized" data (IDs of posts) in Redis and "denormalized" data (other metadata such as likes, shares, text, urls of picture, etc) in Memcached.

So, how it would work is: to render a user's feed, the list of post IDs in a user's message box on a Redis cluster would be fetched and passed to a Memcached cluster from which all metadata relating to each post will be fetched. If there's no data for a post in Memcached, we simply fall back to retrieve it from our main datastore (MySQL).

Comment: check this link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/memcached-vs-redis-which-one-pick-ranjeet-vimal/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the use case that you have descried, it's evident that only one of either Memcached or Redis is sufficient. It would be impractical to use both in the same system.

You can make your decision based on what you are comfortable with using and what you think fits your requirements best. Both redis and memcached store your data in memory, so there will not be an issue speed wise.

Using both is a bad idea because of the below factors:

- You would have to maintain and develop two different memory stores
- Adding an extra layer to your system means more latency overheads

You can go through their respective documentations if you haven't already done so:

[Redis](https://redis.io/documentation)

[Memcached](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki)